# jquery simpleweather not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, yahoo-weather-api

I want to show weather on my web site using [simpleweatherjs](http://simpleweatherjs.com/), but it is not working for me. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Page is blank. If I, for example before line $.simpleWeather({...}); put $("#weather").html("test"), then this sentence work, but it is not working under $.simpleWeather({...}); like it is shown in example.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Weather</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/2.5.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="weather"></div>
<script>
// Docs at http://simpleweatherjs.com
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: 'Austin, TX',
    woeid: '',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
      html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
      html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
      html += '<li>'+weather.wind.direction+' '+weather.wind.speed+' '+weather.units.speed+'</li></ul>';

      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Check your console for errors.

Comment: and error in console? because it works good http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/x34eu/ here.

Comment: console: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&rnd=20141114&diagnosti…2Austin,%20TX%22%20and%20gflags=%22R%22)%20and%20u=%22f%22&_=1393249498897

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running the code from a local file? i.e. navigating to c:\html\test.html (or equivalent) in the browser.

It doesn't appear to work when doing this for me either, however when I hosted the HTML file on a webserver (I used tomcat) and navigated to `http://localhost:8080/html/test/html` it worked.

Edit: This would explain why it works fine on JS Fiddle as well

Comment: Thanks. When I upload file to server then everything works fine, but if I open file on browser then it doesn't work. Thanks again for tip.

Answer (score 1):

try to clear your line:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

maybe there is something set hidden in there.

or/and change the line: (if you are local)

```
//query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql
```

to

```
  http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql
```

Answer (score 0):

Console error says that it is not able to load

```
   //query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql.....
```

Hence prefix the url with http or https like

```
    https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql.....
```